# ActionBar: Up icon and Overflow menu icons not appearing, but working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

The ActionBar on my app, which is a toolbar, does not show the icons for the UP button, nor the overflow menu, just a white bar. **However, these still work- if you touch where they are supposed to be**. They simply are not appearing.

I've compared the theme, xml, and manifests to an older app of mine which did not share the same problems, and found no differences. So I am completely lost.

Styles xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme_NoActionBar" parent= "AppTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>



    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.xu.servicequalityrater.CameraActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >


        <TextView android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Veritas" />



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Manifest excerpt

```
 <activity
            android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoActionBar" />
```

Any advice by members who have faced similar issues is extremely welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, your toolbar `back` icon and `overflow` icon showing as `white` color and I guess you have used `colorPrimary` as `white`.

Change `colorPrimary` to other color OR you can use `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, it will show `back` and `overflow` icon as `black`.

**Here is the fully working code**

**Style.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> <!-- WHITE -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>    
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: You are correct that I use white as my primary color. I just tried your suggestion, no change  :( EDIT: Just changed my primary color to black, and all icons show up . It was a color issue, thank you FAT. I will tweak this until I get white to work.

Comment: If my answer seems useful, I hope you will give an up-vote. :)

Comment: can you amend with your activity xml, full manifest, and styles?

Comment: Okey, just wait a minute

Comment: I have updated my answer as per your requirements. Hope this will help~

Comment: Best of luck :)